What is the relation between the Faraday effect and the Zeeman effect?
The Faraday Effect basically says that certain materials under a magnetic field have different indexes of refraction for right and circular polarized light. Linear light which is a superposition of these two would then change it's polarization.
The Zeeman effect causes splitting of the fine structure of the electron and obeys the selection rules $ \Delta m_{l}=0,\pm 1$. And right and left circular polarized photons have spin.
I am really confused on how both of these are connected?

Most magneto-optic effects, such as the Faraday or Kerr effect, are classical phenomena. You don't need to explain things in terms of photons or atoms to understand these effects. The Zeeman effect was the first quantum mechanical MO effect to be discovered. It only makes sense in the quantum context of atomic light-matter interactions. You can often think of the Zeeman effect as the microscopic explanation of the classical MO effects.

The Zeeman effect exists in classical theory https://lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/history/lorentz/lorentz.html . Maybe anomalous Zeeman effect does not, not sure...

I should have said atomic theory instead.
